# In The Bells of St John, do the symbols used by the Great Intelligence have any meaning?

Tags: doctor-who, languages

They appear as mostly gibberish symbols on screen, as the names of the wifi access points or the code for the computer program run by and for the Great Intelligence, and I was wondering if they have any hidden meaning? References to something else in the Whoverse or another universe, or are they just gibberish?

[image]

Comment: I don't know, Aurebesh?

Comment: @Adamant - It seems to have been inspired by it; https://www.omniglot.com/images/langsamples/smp_aurebesh.gif

Comment: It does look similar indeed.

Answer (score 2):

[image]They may have something to do with the Skasis Paradigm symbols. They look similar, but the signs from the Paradigm seem not to be boxy enough to match those from the program in the picture.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the symbols used by the Skasis Paradigm, to make a comparison? You can include the picture in your answer as I did in my question. Thanks.